# Spotify request access token is not working when refresh url

Tags: php, spotify

Right now i am working on spotify api, When i hit url for first time it is giving me all playlist but when i refresh page again it is giving me exception error, here is my code,

```
require '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session('******', '*******', 'http://localhost:8080/spotify/vendor/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/demo.php'); 
$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {    
    $session->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    $data = $api->setAccessToken($session->getAccessToken());

    $artistData = $api->me();
    $artistId = $artistData->id;
    $playlists = $api->getUserPlaylists($artistId, array(
        'limit' => 5
    ));

    foreach ($playlists->items as $playlist) {
        echo '<a href="' . $playlist->external_urls->spotify . '">' . $playlist->name . '</a> <br>';
    }
} else {
    $scopes = array(
        'scope' => array(
            'user-read-email',
            'user-library-modify',
        ),
    );

    header('Location: ' . $session->getAuthorizeUrl($scopes));
}
```

Here is my exception error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPIException' with message 'Invalid authorization code' in D:\xampp\htdocs\spotify\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php:156 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\spotify\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php(26): SpotifyWebAPI\Request->send('POST', 'https://account...', Array, Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\spotify\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Session.php(233): SpotifyWebAPI\Request->account('POST', '/api/token', Array) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\spotify\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\demo.php(31): SpotifyWebAPI\Session->requestAccessToken('AQAaVZvpXUExKg2...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\spotify\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php on line 156
```

Can anyone please tell me why it cause error ? If anyone have experiance with spotify

Comment: I am working with the same code, and have the same issue, I need to make it work with Drupal, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of the library here.

The only thing I can think of which would yield that error message is if you try to request a access token twice with the same code. Try visiting the URL to your PHP file again but remove any `?code=...` parts.

Comment: Cannot use the same session in another php page? How could I retrieve all data from the logged user?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, #jwilsson and #Ricardo Rios , Can you please give me some example ? What i need to do now ?

Comment: Can you please give me example with code so it wiill be helpful for me

Comment: @Nikul The code is correct but I think you're visiting the same page twice with the same `code` query string which tries to request a access token with the same authorization code again which isn't allowed.

Comment: @RicardoRios You can use the same access token on multiple pages for one hour, but the same authorization code cannot be used twice (the one you get in `$_GET`), that seems to be the problem here.

Comment: I tried with this code still it is giving me error,

Comment: `require '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session('0decc6d817cc4ea48e4a48066a4f507d', '8a003635a94e43e0ab8e8420db9e8bbd', 'http://localhost:8080/spotify/vendor/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/demo.php');
$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();$accessToken = $session->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);
$data = $api->setAccessToken($session->getAccessToken());   
$playlistTracks = $api->getUserPlaylistTracks('spironas','3d6SYQPlxSdDnIAznawPYC');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($playlistTracks);
    die;`

Comment: I removed code parameter from URL, still it is giving me error, #jwilsson, Can you please try with your end sample code,  and give me that code so i can resolve this issue, this is really needed, i am working on this since last 2 days still i didn't get any solution, Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, when I run the code you first posted locally it works. You can't change the authorization code, Spotify just sends it to you and then you send it back unaltered. Try visiting `http://localhost:8080/spotify/vendor/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/demo.php`, it should work cause the code you posted is correct. Make sure to always visit exactly `http://localhost:8080/spotify/vendor/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/demo.php` (no query strings or anything).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94060/discussion-between-nikul-and-jwilsson).